# Node Express - How to support encoded url query string

Tags: node.js, express

Using node v6.2.0, express 4.14.0.

When entering site url as: 'http://site.name/?key=value', I'm able to get the query value by:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) { 
  // req.query.key equals 'value'
});
```

But when entering encoded url: 'http://site.name/?key%3Dvalue', the req.query object looks like this:

```
{ 'key%3Dvalue' : '' }
```

Is there a way to make node req.query to parse the url correctly? 
If no, what is the preferred method to extract this query value?

Comment: It is parsing it correctly. The entire point of encoding the `=` as `%3D` is so that it will be treated as *data* and not as the character which divides the key from the value. Otherwise there would be no way to submit an `=` sign.

Comment: you don't have to encode the "=" if its the delimiter and not part of value itself.

Answer (score 0):

As understood from the comments, the parsing is correct and it shouldn't decode %3D to key delimiter.

In this case there was already clients in the wild that tried to reach the address in encoded url (because of client bug). 
so I've added a temporary handler on the server to parse the '%3D' as '='.

```
const value = req.query.key ||
    url.parse(req.url.replace('%3D', '='), true).query.key;
```

When the clients will rollout a new version with a fix, I could remove this handler from the server and use only req.query.key as it should be.